# Finding a particular word in textarea via voice commands

Tags: javascript

Hey is it possible through regexp to go to a particular word via voice commands.Ex if say go to speech it should go to the speech word and high lite that in text area. I doubt whether it is possible with regexp???

Comment: How will you process the sound?

Comment: *"Hey is it possible..."* - yes. As for how, do a bit more research.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's possible to select text in a textarea automatically, and it's possible to do voice to text, so it's definitely all possible.  How easy it is depends on what browsers you want to support and what your budget is.  Here's an example which only works in google chrome, which uses their x-webkit-speech addon: http://jsfiddle.net/tommcquarrie/RYx4A/

```
<input type="text" x-webkit-speech>
```

(Click on the little microphone icon and say "hamburger" for an example).

If you want to go further than that, then you'll have to look at some other third party speech to text api's.  This is a fairly new space but there's some promising ideas, such as the html5 speech api: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API (currently only supported by chrome), or this third party api which utilises flash: http://speechapi.com/main/

Basically, it's a reasonably new technology in the web application space, so you'll need to do your homework before you start adding this to your site/application.